# || (or) in ternary operator is not working in JS and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-operator

I have the following ternary, that checks if a `prop` named `isChecked` is `true`. If it's true, it checks if another prop is `true`, and if it's true it uses the prop, otherwise, it uses a different variable in an object:

```
props.isChecked ? '2px solid ' + props.theme || vars.blue : '2px solid ' + vars.black 
// if isChecked is true, check if theme is true, and if not use vars.blue, otherwise something else
```

`vars.blue = "1778f2"` |
`vars.black= "111111"`

It only works if I specify the `theme` prop, otherwise it won't work. What's the problem here?

Comment: Try parenthesis. `(props.isChecked ? ('2px solid ' + props.theme)) || vars.blue : '2px solid ' + vars.black`

Comment: Not working ...

Comment: please add all possible values of the variables.

Comment: check the [Operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) and use the parenthesis where required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to take out the suffix and use the terenary without adding the same value.

```
'2px solid ' + (props.isChecked
    ? props.theme || vars.blue
    : vars.black
)
```

Answer (score 1):

`+` has highest [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), then comes `||`, then conditional operator `? ... :`.

Without parentheses, your code will be evaluated like this:

```
props.isChecked ? (('2px solid ' + props.theme) || vars.blue) : ('2px solid ' + vars.black)
```

Parentheses can provide custom operator order. Add the following:

```
//                               v--------------------------v
props.isChecked ? '2px solid ' + ( props.theme || vars.blue ) : '2px solid ' + vars.black
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using template strings.

```js
props.isChecked ? `2px solid ${props.theme || vars.blue}` : `2px solid ${vars.black}`
```

Comment: It's already in a template string. I'm using styled-components.

Comment: What result do you get when you use this line?

Comment: When I click it, it should change the background to the them (which is a color), and if not specified, a variable. But it just does't work. It's just white. and a black border (the border is supposed to be black before clicking)

Answer (score 0):

```
props.isChecked ? '2px solid ' + (props.theme ? vars.blue : vars.black) : ''
```

Check out this one it would work

Answer (score 0):

What happens here is caused by [operators precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

`+` operator has a higher precedence than `||`, so `'2px solid ' + props.theme || vars.blue` will always parse `'2px solid ' + props.theme` first, and then pass the result as the operand to `result || vars.blue`.

In any case, `|| vars.blue` will never by parsed since your string always start by `2px solid` and therefore will never be falsy.

You can fix your ternary expression this way :

```js
props.isChecked ? '2px solid ' + (props.theme || vars.blue) : '2px solid ' + vars.black;
```

Now for code styling, you should avoid to use `+` operator with strings when possible, and use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) when possible :

```js
const result = `2px solid ${props.isChecked ? props.theme || vars.blue : vars.black}`;
```

You will not face operator precedence problem here since you don't mix them, this way.